# Cannot open *.docx file after converting to *.zip

Tags: xml, zip, docx, 7zip

I have a corrupted word document, with a tag error in document.xml. To access document.xml I used to rename the document do a *.zip, and just open the archive. Now for some reason I get a "not an archive" error message as neither windows explorer nor 7zip cannot open the archive. I've managed to do the same conversion on another machine, and send myself the same archive, which did open, but this is not a very convenient solution. How can I get to document.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the file using a text editor (notepad, nano, or vim)

If the file does'nt start with `PK^C^D^T`, it is most likely not a zip file at all, so it means it would be named .docx but not be a docx (any file can have any extension, so extensions are not reliable)

Comment: Thanks, somehow some content got lost while my outlook tried to scan the corrupted file, including this part.